# cxf create client fails in intranet

Tags: cxf

I use wsdl2java to generate code, and succeed to create web service client to invoke the service.
But when i put my program to server machine, the program can't create web service client.if the machine can access internet, everything goes ok. so i think this exception is due to that cxf can't access http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/

stacktrace:

```
14-11-20 18:51:20 create WSUtil err: [main-com.jadic.ws.WSUtil]
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:151) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:101) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_05]
    at com.jadic.ws.czsmk.CenterProcess.<init>(CenterProcess.java:43) ~[stserver-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.jadic.ws.WSUtil.createServiceClient(WSUtil.java:106) [stserver-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.jadic.ws.WSUtil.<init>(WSUtil.java:95) [stserver-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.jadic.ws.WSUtil.getWsUtil(WSUtil.java:76) [stserver-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.jadic.STServer.<init>(STServer.java:34) [stserver-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.jadic.STServer.main(STServer.java:57) [stserver-1.0.0.jar:na]
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:100) ~[cxf-rt-core-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:204) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:149) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException (at /definitions/types/schema): faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'.: java.net.UnknownHostException: schemas.xmlsoap.org
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2198) ~[wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseSchema(WSDLReaderImpl.java:830) ~[wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseSchema(WSDLReaderImpl.java:654) ~[wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseTypes(WSDLReaderImpl.java:610) ~[wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseDefinitions(WSDLReaderImpl.java:320) ~[wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2352) ~[wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2338) ~[wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:261) ~[cxf-rt-core-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:206) ~[cxf-rt-core-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:98) ~[cxf-rt-core-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: schemas.xmlsoap.org
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_05]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_05]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_05]
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_05]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_05]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_05]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_05]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_05]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_05]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_05]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_05]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_05]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_05]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_05]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_05]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_05]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_05]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_05]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_05]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_05]
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2188) ~[wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

so could you tell how to solve this problem,thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove all cxf-related jar, works.

because i did't use cxf library in my code, just use cxf tool to generate stub classes

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring saaj(saaj-impl-1.3.2.jar) in the classpath..